# How to get list of nodes list alongwith the roles and recipes assigned in the runlist within a particular chef environment?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo, knife, cookbook

I am using the following command to get list of nodes in a particular environment.

```
knife node list -e env1
```

How can I modify knife command to also include the run list items within it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't use `knife node list` for this. Most knife commands are very direct wrappers for their underlying REST API calls. If you want to build a script for displaying in a particular format, you probably want to use `knife exec` or skip knife entirely and use something like the `chef-api` gem or `PyChef` Python library.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
knife search node "roles:$ROLENAME"
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you half way, all nodes with their run list. You can also filter with the "environment/env" attribute

`knife search node "*" -a run_list`